# Which is bigger? $a$ or $a^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which is bigger: $a$ or $a^2$ and what is the proof of that?

I'm kinda stuck and because there are cases where $a$ is bigger and other cases where $a^2$ is bigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Factorize $a^2 - a$. When is this number greater than or smaller than $0$?

Comment: a(a-1)=0
a1=0
a2=1
Means that for any number, it would be a^2>a, except 0 and 1?

Comment: The product of two numbers is positive if both factors are positive **or** if both factors are negative.

Comment: Thanks. English ain't my first language so if I may ask what do you mean by factors?

Comment: In the expression (*product*) $x \cdot y$, the two numbers $x$ and $y$ are called *factors*.

Answer (score 0):

$a>a^2:\ 0<a<1$

$a<a^2:\ \text{for all other }a,a\neq0,1$